# I have a class representing coredata - how do i add a getter?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data

I have a class, called Media, which represents coredata. If something changes in my database, i'll do Editor > Create NSManagedObject Subclass, and this will re-write the .h and .m files for the class.

I want to add a getter method though. As far as i'm aware, I can't do this through a category. What's the best way to go about doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at [mogenerator](https://github.com/rentzsch/mogenerator), one of the most useful pieces of code available to the Cocoa community.

> Unlike Xcode, mogenerator manages two classes per entity: one for
>   machines, one for humans
>
> The machine class can always be overwritten to match the data model,
>   with humans’ work effortlessly preserved

Answer (score 1):

Copy getter, rewrite class, paste getter.  :-)

If you've multiple files, and assuming you use a code-versioning system (which you should!), you can use the Versioning Editor to just copy the getter from the "old" file.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a Category to an NSManagedObject subclass. Have it in a separate file, and don't name your getter the same as your managed object variables (so technically it's no longer a getter, but its a method on your managed object that could access whatever you want). This won't be deleted when you regenerate your class.